# Using sed to delete a whole line if it contains only specific number

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a txt file

```
123
456
789
456
123456
```

I want to delete specific characters from the file i.e (123). 
I tried with

```
$ sed -i '/123/d' dummy.sh
$ vi dumm.txt
456
789
456
```

In the below command when I run both the words (`123` and `123456`) are getting deleted but I need to delete only `123` from the file

```
$ sed -i 's/123//g' dummy.sh
$ vi dumm.txt
456
789
456
456
```

when I run the below command the `123` is getting replaced with null.

Can anyone say how to delete a whole line if it contains only specific number?

Comment: In a word - [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: i did not get what you are asking ?

Comment: Note that while it is perfectly ok to use sed for this task, grep is the tool which was created specifically to display or hide lines of input matching the pattern. In this case the following grep command would do the same: grep -E -v '^123$' dumm.txt

Comment: @Gnudiff I don't see any advantage of `grep` if you use is like that. But it can be superior for some tasks due to it's options: `grep -xv 123`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is unclear if you are trying to delete whole line with `123` or replace it with empty line. Anyhow, just add anchors of beginning `^` and end `$` of line to your pattern:

```
sed -i '/^123$/d' dummy.sh      #delete whole line
sed -i 's/^123$//' dummy.sh     #replace with empty line
```

Comment: Yep i got my answer thank you :) . I am trying to delete the whole line here.